# Sort XML by the first word in attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file(below is a part of it) with more than 1000 lines of code like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<exchange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<viewpoints>    
    <view name="002. PG vs MD - Overview">
            <viewpoint tool="none" render="shaded" lighting="headlight" focal="30.3740807783">
                <camera projection="persp" near="1.0000000000" far="10.0000000000" aspect="1.4551804424" height="0.7853981634">
                    <position>
                        <pos3f x="14.2834498406" y="-183.6741132934" z="35.6151508952"/>
                    </position>
                    <rotation>
                        <quaternion a="0.3979643079" b="0.0563656552" c="0.1284089725" d="0.9066192466"/>
                    </rotation>
                </camera>
            </viewpoint>
        </view>

        <view name="004. EL vs MD - Overview">
            <viewpoint tool="none" render="shaded" lighting="headlight" focal="30.3740807783">
                <camera projection="persp" near="1.0000000000" far="10.0000000000" aspect="1.4551804424" height="0.7853981634">
                    <position>
                        <pos3f x="14.2834498406" y="-183.6741132934" z="35.6151508952"/>
                    </position>
                    <rotation>
                        <quaternion a="0.3979643079" b="0.0563656552" c="0.1284089725" d="0.9066192466"/>
                    </rotation>
                </camera>
            </viewpoint>
        </view>
    </viewpoints>
</exchange>
```

I would like to sort the code above using the attribute "name" but I would like it to sort using the first word in the attribute value. In the above example, I would like it sore using **PG/EL**.

P.S: Please note that I'm not very familiar with XSLT or any other tools, but I can probably understand it with little explanation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. The following XLST sorts the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="viewpoints/view">
          <xsl:sort select="substring-after(substring-before(@name, 'vs'), '.')" order="ascending"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
     </root>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="view">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this code removes all the tags that are before the "`<view>`" tag and replaces it with "`<root>`". and it edits the view tag as follows "`<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name=" #viewname# ">`". The following is the output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>

    <view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="004. EL vs MD - Overview">
        <viewpoint tool="none" render="shaded" lighting="headlight" focal="30.3740807783">
            <camera projection="persp" near="1.0000000000" far="10.0000000000" aspect="1.4551804424" height="0.7853981634">
                <position>
                    <pos3f x="14.2834498406" y="-183.6741132934" z="35.6151508952"/>
                </position>
                <rotation>
                    <quaternion a="0.3979643079" b="0.0563656552" c="0.1284089725" d="0.9066192466"/>
                </rotation>
            </camera>
        </viewpoint>
    </view>

<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="002. PG vs MD - Overview">
        <viewpoint tool="none" render="shaded" lighting="headlight" focal="30.3740807783">
            <camera projection="persp" near="1.0000000000" far="10.0000000000" aspect="1.4551804424" height="0.7853981634">
                <position>
                    <pos3f x="14.2834498406" y="-183.6741132934" z="35.6151508952"/>
                </position>
                <rotation>
                    <quaternion a="0.3979643079" b="0.0563656552" c="0.1284089725" d="0.9066192466"/>
                </rotation>
            </camera>
        </viewpoint>
    </view>

</root>
```

How to correct this?

PS: please look at the XML code above

Answer (score 2):

You've given an example with two elements to be sorted, and for both elements, the "first word" can be obtained as `substring(@name, 6, 2)` or as `substring-after(substring-before(@name, ' '), ' ')`. If either of these expressions work for all your data, then use them as the sort key in `xsl:sort`. Otherwise, you need to tell us

(a) what exactly you mean by a "word"

(b) what version of XSLT you are using (any more complex string manipulation is going to be an awful lot easier if you can use XSLT 2.0)

Comment: I think "substring-after(substring-before(@name, ' '), ' ')" would work for me. I'll have to give it a try

Comment: But just to confirm, does this work with space(' ')? i.e.,  (@name, ' ')  would this work in detecting the space?

Comment: I think the onus is on you to explain the requirements more carefully. You haven't said what you mean by "the first word"; I have guessed, and I have almost certainly guessed wrong. Actually, you haven't answered either of my questions.

Comment: a: By first word, I mean the word that comes after the number in the name attribute(i.e., word after  002./004.) which in this case is PG/EL
b: I'm very new to XSLT, and I haven't yet created any stylesheet for this specific issue. I actually don't know how to. I need to work on this a little.

Comment: To write the logic to extract the sort key, we need to know about what kind of values can appear in the name attribute. Will it always be three digits, then full stop, then space, then two letters? If not, what else might it be? And if it's something else, what are the rules for extracting the "first word"?

Comment: The number of digits might vary, but it will always be ("number" & "full stop" & "Space" & "First word" & "Space" & second word"). So I think I can use 

substring-after(substring-before(@name, ' '), '')

 i.e., after "space" and before "space". But I'm not sure if this works with space

Comment: Actually "substring-after(substring-before(@name, 'vs'), '.')" i.e., before "vs" and after"full stop". This might be the solution for me