# Best way to apply an XSL file to an XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I recently had few XML & XSL questions( [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884476/group-similar-nodes-in-xml-using-xlst) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777055/sort-xml-by-the-first-word-in-attribute-value)) for which I found solutions. I am currently applying these XSL file to the XML using the "[XML tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/)" plugin for Notepad++. But I think this only works with XSL 1.0.

So I was wondering what is the best way to apply XSL within the XML file for sorting & adding nodes in an XML file and saving it as a new file.(Preferably open source application)

Answer (score 0):

Install an XSLT processor like [Saxon](http://saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml), and call this from the command line:

```
Transform -s:source.xml -xsl:stylesheet.xsl -o:out.xml
```

Comment: I was actually looking for an open source application